# Neo4j schema denormalization

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, graph-databases

In my Neo4j application I have a products, products characteristics and list of votes(with double weight) for each product on a certain characteristic.

In order to sort a list of products by average weight of votes for a list of characteristics I need to perform a complex run-time Cypher query that will calculate a sum of avg weight for list of characteristics for each product.

This is my current Cypher query:

```
MATCH (parentP:Product)-[:CONTAINS]->(childP:Product)
WHERE id(parentP) = {productId}
WITH childP
OPTIONAL MATCH (p:Product)<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(v:Vote)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c:Characteristic)
WHERE id(p) = id(childP) AND id(c) IN {characteristicIds}
WITH childP, c, avg(v.weight) as weight
RETURN childP AS product, sum(weight) as weight
ORDER BY weight DESC
```

I know that Neo4j is extremely fast for graph traversal but no so good for aggregation (summing, counting, averaging, and so on). My system can have a large lists of votes for each characteristic on each product.

Please help me to denormilize this structure in order to avoid any performance issues with a big lists of votes.

**PROFILE output for Brian's query:**

Cypher version: CYPHER 2.2, planner: COST. 374933 total db hits in 1482 ms.

[image: PROFILE output]

Comment: Perhaps you can share a sample database that helps us execute the query?

Comment: I have added sample database and query

Comment: How fast are you wanting the query to run?  My first run on your DB took 2.1 seconds and after the first query it's taking about 0.5 second

Comment: This is a small sample database.. the real database is a much bigger.. I want to make this schema/query independent by performance from Votes list size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know that I would say that Neo4j isn't good for aggregation.  You might be able to help it save some work by specifically including your `childP` in your second match:

```
MATCH (parentP)-[:CONTAINS]->(childP:Product)
WHERE id(parentP) = {productId}
OPTIONAL MATCH childP<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(v:Vote)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c)
WHERE id(c) IN {characteristicIds}
WITH childP, c, avg(v.weight) as weight
RETURN childP AS product, sum(weight) as weight
ORDER BY weight DESC
```

I want to make sure I understand what you're asking for, though.  Is this query performing poorly?  Are you trying to prevent it from performing poorly in the future?

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Performance on aggregation was mentioned at "Learning Neo4j" ebook by Rik Van Bruggen  - http://neo4j.com/book-learning-neo4j/ (page 40) - "If you are trying to put together large lists of things,
effectively sets, that do not require a lot of joining or require a lot of aggregation
(summing, counting, averaging, and so on) on these sets, then the performance of
the graph database compared to other database management systems will be not as
favorable"

Comment: Also, when I add 1 vote  for each characteristic on each product everything works fine. In case of 100 votes for each characteristic on each product I can see the slowdown.

Comment: Yeah, I suppose compared to some other databases it would be slower.  I agree with albert that you should do some profiling.  Also one thing that I do is change `WITH`s in my Query to `RETURN`s and drop the rest to see where the performance is slow.

Comment: Perhaps you can attach a query plan for Brian's query for the slow case? You can just prepend your query with PROFILE in shell or browser.

Comment: Sure, I have added image with a query plan to my question body

Comment: So I played around with your database some.  I would definitely remove the `WITH childP`.  Beyond that, you can remove the label definitions for `parentD` and `c` since you're specifying them by ID (I would change the `c` variable, at least, to make it clear what it is for readers).  See my updated answer.  That might help some.

Comment: From the profile, though, it seems like the slowness is from having to traverse so much data, not really the aggregation.  For such a large aggregation to a DB I might not expect the query to be necessarily quick.  What do you plan on using the query for?

Comment: may be when a new Vote appears I can store precalculated avg value somewhere in this schema ?

Comment: Yeah, certainly.  You could create cache relationships between Products and Characteristics, or you could create a node which points at both.  Then you could just have a Cypher query to delete them and another to build them.  You might also consider something like Redis which is build for cache invalidation

Comment: Thanks Brian, right now I have implemented the structure described in the my following ticket http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31906811/neo4j-cypher-delete-query I'm taking care about correct values for VoteGroup.avgVotesWeight and VoteGroup.totalVotesCount in my CRUD for Votes. Looks like the new query works much more faster right now -

Comment: MATCH (parentD)-[:CONTAINS]->(childD:Decision) WHERE id(parentD) = {decisionId} OPTIONAL MATCH childD<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(vg:VoteGroup)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c) WHERE id(c) IN {criteriaIds} WITH childD, vg.avgVotesWeight as weight RETURN childD AS decision, sum(weight) as weight ORDER BY weight DESC

Answer (score 0):

If we are speaking about performance problems, it would be useful to attach profiling information: http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/how-do-i-profile-a-query.html

Then will be easier to decide where to act.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try:

```
MATCH (c:Characteristic) WHERE id(c) IN {characteristicIds} 
WITH collect(c) as characteristics

MATCH (parentP:Product)-[:CONTAINS]->(childP:Product)
WHERE id(parentP) = {productId}
OPTIONAL MATCH childP<-[:VOTED_FOR]-(v:Vote)
WITH childP, v, head(filter(c in characteristics WHERE (v)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c))) as c
WHERE c is not null
WITH childP, c, avg(v.weight) as weight
RETURN childP AS product, sum(weight) as weight
ORDER BY weight DESC
```

As there are much fewer vote on a product than votes per characteristic, we start with those and then check against characteristics. Without a db it is hard to say though.

Comment: The PROFILE output for this query - Cypher version: CYPHER 2.2, planner: COST. 1624443 total db hits in 4303 ms.

Comment: I hoped that it would use the optimimized `ExpandInto` operation for this part ` WHERE (v)-[:VOTED_ON]->(c)`

Comment: But still without a sample database it's hard to help :)