# Neo4j Cypher delete query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j, graph-databases

I have a following Neo4j Cypher query for `Decision` entity deleting:

```
MATCH (d:Decision) 
WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]-(t) 
DELETE d, r WITH t, r 
WHERE NOT (id(t) IN {decisionsIds}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[r2:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR]-() 
WHERE r2 <> r WITH t, r2 
WHERE none(x in labels(t) WHERE x in ['User', 'Decision']) DELETE t, r2
```

Previously I had a `Vote` entity with relationships `VOTED_ON` and `VOTED_FOR` to entities `Criterion` and `Decision`. Also, `Vote` has relationship `CREATED_BY` to `User` entity.

Everything worked fine.

Today, I have changed this schema. I have introduced new `VoteGroup` entity.
Now, `VoteGroup` instead of `Vote` contains relationships `VOTED_ON` and `VOTED_FOR` to entities `Criterion` and `Decision`:

```
@NodeEntity
public class VoteGroup extends BaseEntity {

    private static final String VOTED_ON = "VOTED_ON";
    private final static String VOTED_FOR = "VOTED_FOR";
    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @RelatedTo(type = VOTED_FOR, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Decision decision;

    @RelatedTo(type = VOTED_ON, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Criterion criterion;

    @RelatedTo(type = CONTAINS, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private Set<Vote> votes = new HashSet<>();

    private double avgVotesWeight;

    private long totalVotesCount;

.....

}
```

`Vote` entity now looks like:

```
@NodeEntity
public class Vote extends BaseEntity {

    private final static String CONTAINS = "CONTAINS";
    private final static String CREATED_BY = "CREATED_BY";

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    @RelatedTo(type = CONTAINS, direction = Direction.INCOMING)
    private VoteGroup group;

    @RelatedTo(type = CREATED_BY, direction = Direction.OUTGOING)
    private User author;

    private double weight;

....
}
```

Please help me to change the mentioned Cypher query in order to delete `Votes`. After my schema changes it now deletes `VoteGroups`(it's okay) but doesn't deletes `Votes`. I need to delete `Votes` and relationships between `Votes` and `User` also.

**UPDATED**

The new following query working now(at least all my tests passed):

```
MATCH (d:Decision) 
WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds} 
OPTIONAL MATCH (d)-[r]-(t) 
DELETE d, r 
WITH t, r 
WHERE NOT (id(t) IN {decisionsIds}) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (t)-[r2:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR]-()-[r3:CONTAINS]-(t2) 
WHERE r2 <> r 
WITH t, r2, t2, r3 
WHERE none(x in labels(t) 
WHERE x in ['User', 'Decision']) 
DELETE t, r2, t2, r3
```

but I'm still not sure that this query is 100% correct... Anyway, I'll add a bunch of tests in order to check everything.

Could you please validate this query also? **Especially I'm not sure that deleted all the relationships and did not leave the garbage in the database.**

Answer (score 0):

Looks pretty complicated.

Can't you just specify the path and delete the whole path?

```
MATCH (d:Decision) WHERE id(d) IN {decisionsIds} 
OPTIONAL MATCH path = (d)-[r1:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR]->(t)<-[r2:VOTED_ON|:CREATED_BY|:VOTED_FOR]-()
DELETE path

// or 
DELETE d,t,r1,r2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! `VoteGroup` and `Vote` are not only the entities associated with `Decision`. `Decision` also contains child `Decision` and defines list of `Criterion` and `CriterionGroup`. They also must be deleted. But `User` should not be deleted.. only relationships with him. The original query in the question did a good job until I have introduced new `VoteGroup` and reassociated `Vote` to this entity. Now, `VoteGroup` instead of `Vote` contains relationships `VOTED_ON` and `VOTED_FOR` to entities `Criterion` and `Decision`.

Comment: So, right now for pair of `Criterion` and `Decision` I can have one `VoteGroup` and a list of `Vote` associated with this `VoteGroup`. Previously I had a list of `Vote` and each of them was associated with pair of  `Criterion` and `Decision`

Comment: Unfortunately, the query in this answer doesn't work as expected

Comment: I have created new query (updated my question with it). Could you please also check it ? Thanks!